# Definition of independence of random variables.

Tags: measure-theory

I am given the following definition of independence of random variables.

Let $f_1: \Omega \rightarrow \Omega_1$, $f_2: \Omega \rightarrow \Omega_2$. The random variables are independent if for any $A_1\in\Omega_1$, $A_2\in\Omega_2$ the events $f_1\in A_1$, $f_2\in A_2$ are independent.

My question, is this correct or should not $A_1\in F_1$ (i.e. the sigma algebra).

Comment: @ZacharySelk It's the definition I was provided with. Maybe a definition rather than the definition ;).

Comment: @ZacharySelk That's why the question... This is almost directly cut and pasted. There is some added verbiage "for any measurable events $A_1\in \omega$", "the events $f_1\in A_1$...".

Comment: @ZacharySelk Would you say it's correct with the correction I proposed? (Also a typo in my above comment, $\omega$ should have been $\Omega_1$.)

Comment: Yes. $\qquad\qquad$